# Power BI DAX : CROSS JOIN between two tables based on a variable filter

Tags: variables, filter, powerbi, dax, cross-join

I have two input tables in my Power BI model.

1. UserPermission
2. Lookup Table

The above two tables are **not** related.

**UserPermission:**

[image]

'All' corresponds to all the segments in the Lookup Table, i.e. X,Y,Z.

**Lookup Table:**

[image]

UserPermission[SgmtID] is equivalent to LookupTable[SegmentID].

I need to develop an output table, by CROSS JOINing the UserName column
in the UserPermission table, and the Ports column in the Lookup Table.

**Desired Output table:**

[image]

David needs to have all the ports of **all the segments**
in the lookup table (i.e. X,Y,Z).

John needs to have all the ports of **segment X** only.

Mike needs to have all the ports of **segment Y** only.

Jill needs to have all the ports of **segments X and Z** only.

The difference between David and Jill is that David can access all segments, while Jill can access multiple segments, but **not** all segments.

The output table is needed for Row Level Security (RLS).

I know to use CROSS JOIN using VALUES, also some variables and filters. But not able to develop a full DAX query, due to lack of expertise.

Can anyone kindly help me with this?

Comment: Are there other users that have multiple segments like David?

Comment: This is probably easier in the query editor. Is there a reason you need it in DAX?

Comment: yes,there are many people are like david; they can see all segments; the purpose of the output table is for Row Level Security (RLS)

Comment: @Agustin Palacios     there are also people such as jill, who can access multiple segments, but not all segments.  Hence,  Jill will have multiple lines in the UserPermission table; but anyone such as david will always have only one line in the UserPermission table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the [SUMMARIZECOLUMNS function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/summarizecolumns-function-dax) is probably the easiest one to achieve this with if you need to do this in DAX.

```
Output Table =
FILTER (
    SUMMARIZECOLUMNS (
        UserPermission[UserName],
        LookupTable[Ports],
        LookupTable[SegmentID],
        "SID", VALUES ( UserPermission[SegmentID] )
    ),
    [SID] < 0 || [SID] = [SegmentID]
)
```

Recommended reading on this powerful function:

https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/introducing-summarizecolumns/

---

**Edit:** If you rename `UserPermissions[SegmentID]` to `UserPermissions[SgmtID]` so that there aren't two columns of the same name when summarizing, then you can write the combined table as follows and avoid the issue you mentioned in the comments:

```
Output Table =
FILTER (
    SUMMARIZECOLUMNS (
        UserPermission[UserName],
        UserPermission[SgmtID],
        LookupTable[Ports],
        LookupTable[SegmentID]
    ),
    [SgmtID] < 0 || [SegmentID] = [SgmtID]
)
```

Comment: thanks Alexis; it works; i will check on Monday, with real data, and afterwards mark your solution as answer

Comment: it works; but I have a special case, where a user called jill can access two segments, but not all segments; the expression you gave throws errors when i add jill; possible to modify the expression?  you can see the extra visual in the post above for the UserPermission  table.; thanks and greatly appreciate your help.

Comment: thanks Alexis; it works; I will use the code in our client report tomorrow, and update you, and should be able to mark your solution as answer tomorrow; thanks very much for your great help. appreciate it.

Comment: thanks you very much; appreciate your GREAT help

Comment: i have a question regarding Power BI scheduled refresh -   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66081047/power-bi-service-automated-schedule-refresh-error-type-mismatch-data-typ                    possible to look into it? greatly appreciate it.

Comment: i have a new DAX Time Intelligence question. Will it be possible to have a look at it:     https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66712386/microsoft-power-bi-dax-time-intelligence-measure-change-context-to-reflect-p