# Microsoft Power BI and DAX - compute percentage change across previous year week numbers for non YTD measures

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, business-intelligence

I have a scenario in a Power BI Matrix visual, where I have a simple measure, called SalesAmount.
It is a simple sum based on a single column of a table, called FactSales.

I have a Date dimension (Calendar) table in my model called Dates2.

I have developed a matrix report as below. This report uses a WeekNumber from the Dates2 table.
I have also developed another measure called SalesAmount_SWLY to get the SalesAmount measure for
the same week in the previous year. My Week Number cycle is Monday to Sunday (not the default Sunday to Saturday cycle).

[image]

[image]

(The first of the above 2 visuals is the actual report, the second one is just to show you, how the measure for the corresponding week of the previous year is stored.)

It is important to note that the measure, SalesAmount is NOT cumulative (non-YTD), i.e. for Week-10 of a year, we do NOT need to add Week-1 to Week-10 sales, but show only Week-10 sales.
But the year totals are aggregated across all the weeks for a given year.

I then develop a measure to generate the percentage change, in parallel weeks. For example, Week-1 of 2020 is compared with Week-1 of 2019, to develop the % change.

Formula for % change in Week-1 of 2020 = {(Value in Week-1 of 2020) - (Value in Week-1 of 2019)}/ (Value in Week-1 of 2019)

Formula for % change in 2020 = {(Total of all the weeks of 2020) - (Total of all the weeks of 2019)}/ (Total of all the weeks of 2019)

This works fine, but for one issue. In the year 2021, we have data only for 2 weeks. (Assume that as of today, we have completed only 2 weeks in 2021, even though we are in September)

As far as the percentage change is concerned, for the aggregated total of 2021 (the last column of the matrix on the right side), we need to compare the aggregated total of the first 2 weeks of 2021, with the corresponding total of the first two weeks of 2020.

[image]

In the visual above, I do not want to see -95.66%, but -18.75%.

Logic: we have completed only two weeks in 2021

Aggregated value in 2021 = 13 (i.e. 6 + 7)

Aggregated value in 2020 = 16  (i.e. 1 + 15, for the first two weeks alone in 2020)

(Currently the 2020 value is taken as 300, which is incorrect)

**Percentage change = (13-16)/16 = -18.75 % (needed in the report)**

**Percentage change = (13-300)/300 = -95.66 % (currently shown in the report, incorrect)**

I posted a similar question a few months back, for percentage change across months across different years:

[Microsoft Power BI - DAX Time Intelligence measure - change context to reflect proper % change; non-YTD measures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66712386/microsoft-power-bi-dax-time-intelligence-measure-change-context-to-reflect-p/66712996#66712996)

Can someone help me solve this percentage change issue across Week Numbers, using a new measure in DAX ?

Logic:

1. I am using the 7-day cycle from Monday to Sunday, to compute week numbers in the Dates2 table. The column name is **WeekNumber** in the Dates2 table.

I compute the measure for the same week number last year, using the below formula:

```
SalesAmount_SWLY = CALCULATE(

                             [SalesAmount], 

                              FILTER(

                                     ALL(Dates2),

                                     Dates2[Year] = SELECTEDVALUE(Dates2[Year]) - 1
                                     &&
                                     Dates2[WeekNumber] = SELECTEDVALUE(Dates2[WeekNumber])

                                   )

                             )
```

2. I am fine in the way I compute percentage change between individual weeks of different years, say Week-5 of 2020 and Week-5 of 2019. Similary the corresponding week numbers of any two consecutive years.
3. I have a challenge in computing the yearly (grand) percentage change between the most recent year (2021), and the previous year (2020) (this is because, in 2021, we have not completed all the weeks)
4. I have just 'n' weeks in 2021. The grand total for 2021 across all the 'n' weeks is fine;  n < 53 (mostly, until the full year is completed).
5. I go to the previous year 2020. **Find the date of the 7th day of the nth week of 2020.** Let me call this date X. This is considered the end date for the previous year (2020).
6. The grand total for 2020, is computed from Jan 1 to date X. This value is used to compute the yearly percentage change from 2020 to 2021.

For the yearly (grand) percentage change across consecutive years, I need to take the grand total for both the years, only when both years have 53 weeks of data. For the most recent year (say 2021), I will most often not have all the weeks. In this case, **between 2021 and 2020** (only), I compare the data only for the first 'n' weeks. For all other cases, things are normal.

And this below logic needs to be accounted in the code:

Say 2016, I have all 53 weeks, but in 2017 I have only the first 50 weeks (no data in Week-51 or Week-52 or Week-53), because no data was recorded for the last 3 weeks of 2017.

When I do the % comparison between 2017 and 2016, in a case like this, I need the grand total of the matrix for 2017 to use all the weeks of both the years, and NOT stop with only 50 weeks of 2016.

In essence, I need the main logic of cutting the weeks short for the previous year, ONLY for the current year, i.e. 2021, and when we are yet to complete all the 53 weeks of the current year.

Comment: @Alexis Olson    Is it possible to look into this ?

Comment: Any idea? not heard from anyone so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SalesAmount_SWLY = 

                   VAR LastYear = YEAR(

                                        MAXX(
                                             ALL(FactSales),
                                             FactSales[Date]
                                            )

                                      )


                   VAR LastDateOfRecordedSales = MAXX(

                                                       FILTER(

                                                               ALL(FactSales),

                                                               YEAR(FactSales[Date]) = MAX(Dates2[Year])
                                                               &&
                                                               ISBLANK(FactSales[Sales]) = FALSE

                                                              ),

                                                        FactSales[Date]

                                                       )


                   VAR MaxWeekNumber = IF(
                                     
                                           MAX(Dates2[Year]) = LastYear,

                                           WEEKNUM(LastDateOfRecordedSales, 2),

                                           53

                                          )


                   VAR SWLY = CALCULATE(

                                          [SalesAmount], 

                                          FILTER(

                                                  ALL(Dates2),

                                                  Dates2[Year] = SELECTEDVALUE(Dates2[Year]) - 1
                                                  &&
                                                  Dates2[WeekNumber] = SELECTEDVALUE(Dates2[WeekNumber])

                                                )

                                       )


                   VAR SWLYtotal = CALCULATE(

                                               [SalesAmount], 

                                               FILTER(

                                                       ALL(Dates2),

                                                       Dates2[Year] = SELECTEDVALUE(Dates2[Year]) - 1
                                                       &&
                                                       Dates2[WeekNumber] <= MaxWeekNumber

                                                     )

                                            )


                   RETURN

                          IF(

                              (HASONEVALUE(Dates2[Year]) = TRUE && HASONEVALUE(Dates2[WeekNumber]) = TRUE),

                              SWLY,

                              IF(

                                 (HASONEVALUE(Dates2[Year]) = TRUE && HASONEVALUE(Dates2[WeekNumber]) = FALSE),

                                 SWLYtotal,

                                 BLANK()

                                )

                             )
```

Comment: @user9824134    thanks very much for your help;  finally figured out; I have the above solution posted here;

Answer (score 0):

```
Count Previous Year EOWEEK =
VAR EquivDateLastYear =
    DATEADD ( DATEADD ( MAX ( [FactTable[Date] ), -1, YEAR ), 1, DAY )
RETURN
    IF (
        HASONEVALUE ( Dates2[Month] ),
        IF (
            [Count] <> BLANK (),
            CALCULATE ( [Count], SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR ( Dates2[Date] ) )
        ),
        IF (
            HASONEVALUE ( Dates2[Year] ),
            CALCULATE (
                [Count],
                DATESBETWEEN (
                    Dates2[Date],
                    EDATE ( MIN ( Dates2[Date] ), -12 ),
                    EquivDateLastYear - WEEKDAY ( EquivDateLastYear, 2 ) + 5
                )
            )
        )
    )
```

This should give you YTD in the prior year through Friday of the eqivalent week.  Manipulate the "+5" portion if you need your dates to end on a different day of the week.

Comment: thanks very much, am looking into it; will get back on Monday. Just a quick question (2021 Vs 2020 comparison):      If I say 2021 has only 2 weeks, then for the aggregated value of the matrix at the row level, I need the grand total of 2021 (which obviously has just 2 weeks) to be compared with the grand total of the first 2 weeks of 2020; this is based on WEEKNUMBER of 2020, and not a particular date; i need an aggregation from the 1st to the nth week number of 2020.   For me, this 'n' value matters, and it is what should determine the YTD ending date of 2020. Are we going along this line ?

Comment: regarding the +5 logic:    I have developed weeknumbers using a Monday to Sunday cycle (as opposed to the default   Sunday to Saturday cycle). Should I change 5 to some other number ?

Comment: I have added a portion called 'Logic' in the main question.   I need the end date reference for the previous year, based on the nth week of this year.